# How to make multiple tables?

Tags: tables

How to make multiple tables on the same page, as in the example?[image]

Comment: Maybe it might be better to see it as a single, more complex table—to ease in actually writing the content.

Comment: Do you have a smaller figure?

Answer (score 5):

```
 \begin{tabular}{l}a\\b\end{tabular}
 \begin{tabular}{l}a\\b\end{tabular}
 \begin{tabular}{l}a\\b\end{tabular}
```

will put three tables in a row.

Comment: Three tables in a same line means that the image will stay horizontal, rather than vertical tables?.

Comment: @benedito sorry I have no idea what you mean by that comment, the text in your image is not rotated? (Questions should _always_ include a complete sample document) The three tables in this answer are tall and thin as in your picture, with 1 column and 2 rows a above b. (incidentally why not simply make it one table?)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. What I want are six tables (separated, but on the same pages-as thin and tall six cards).
I've tried to do a table, but they stay together. I can't separate them. In fact, in my attempts, they're not separated as six cards, that what I want.

Comment: @benedito so the code I suggested should work

Comment: For some space between the tables, add \hskip 1em between the tabular environments.

Comment: @Aditya yes or whatever space is required: as written there will be a normal word-space between them, but as with words additional space can be added if needed.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.8pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|r@{\qquad}r|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{1}\\  & \\
 3 & 3 \\ & 5 \\
 5 & 3 \\ & 7  \\
 7 & 3 \\ & 9 \\
 9 & 4 \\ & 1 \\
 1 & 4 \\
 1 & 3 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}[t]{|r@{\qquad}r|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{1}\\
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{6} \\
 1 & 49 \\ 7 & \\
 1 & 50 \\ 8 & \\
 1 & 51 \\ 9 & \\
 2 & 52 \\ 0 & \\
 2 &  53 \\ & 7 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: And here's the result:]